# Information extracting from plain text using NLP

Tags: nlp, text-mining

Me and my friends working on a hobby project and trying to extract data from plain text. Not something too complicated, just trying to extract name, birth date or somethings like that.

Let's say that we have a text file like this,

"Hello my name is John and I'm 22 years old. I'm living in USA and I like playing video games"

We want to fill a table like this
Name: John
Age: 22
From: USA

Looking for NLP since like last week and I don't even know where to start. Every kind of help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like NER (Named Entity Recognition) is what you are looking for.

Here a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) that explains what NER is.

For the operative part, I suggest you have a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-named-entity-recognition-ner-using-spacy/), but you can find a lot of free guides on the Internet.

Basically, you will have a code that looks like this, more or less:

```py
import spacy # spaCy is a python module to work with NLP
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') # loads english NLP model (small)
sentence = "Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion" # here you will type your sentence
doc = nlp(sentence) # process the sentence with the nlp model and retrieve entities
for ent in doc.ents: # for every entity, print text, start index, end index, label (what type of entity it is)
    print(ent.text, ent.start_char, ent.end_char, ent.label_)
```